# launch WPF application with keyboard shortcut

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to assign a keyboard shortcut to launch my wpf application like window+E for windows explorer.
How can I achieve it?

I know how to assign keys by creating  shortcut link of program.But I want the same behavior on every machine .So that if someone presses a Key my WPF program launches.

Comment: This isn't a programming question - application keyboard shortcuts can be assigned in Windows

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I still think its a programming question.

Comment: You can make service that starts with windows load and wich can hook to keypressed event and launch main application.

Comment: It's not a programming question.  Windows configuration is NOT programming.

Comment: Hi the only thing I can think of, is creating a w32/w64 or interop app/service, running in the background and grabbing all kb events from the windows message pump, then once the right combo is hit, you could launch your app. I really wouldn't do this though.

Comment: I think it **is** a programming question. The OP clearly states he knows about the windows configuration solution to the problem, but they want to achieve the effect without that configuration. They don't state it __explicitly__ that they want code, but from the tags it is quite clear that a c# solution is preferred. What the question lacks is showing us the efforts already made...

Comment: I am looking for a similar option, so I would like to know what worked for you TRS?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a separate application/service, which will have to register a global hotkey, and you can start your application from that app/service.

See this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20141017230556/http://www.liensberger.it:80/web/blog/?p=207) for more details on how to set up a global hotkey in c#.

Or you can distribute a [shortcut with your application with already set up hotkey](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001130.htm), and place it in one of those folders during installation:

- `%UserProfile%\desktop`
- `%AllUsersProfile%\desktop`
- `%UserProfile%\Start Menu`
- `%AllUsersProfile%\Start Menu`

This should also work, as this hotkeys are not stored in the registry, but are scanned at logon (and only from those 4 folders) and are actually kept in memory (source: [this thread](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/19797-45-custom-shortcut-keys-list-remove)).

Of course this latter option has the drawback to only work with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> modifiers, as all shourtcut hotkeys.

Comment: Thanks for link,I hope all the down voters for my question can understand your point.

Comment: @qqbenq can you fix the link you provided?

Comment: @derekantrican: I updated the link to a [stored version in wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20141017230556/http://www.liensberger.it:80/web/blog/?p=207), hope it helps.